# Recursive named captures: Parsing a RESTful URI

Tags: regex, url, rest, uri

I am attempting to breakdown a standard RESTful URI using regular expressions in Ruby.

Assume that we are working on a music discography web application. We have many Artists, which have many Albums, which have many Songs.

With this setup, the following RESTful URIs should all be available as GET requests:

```
/artists
/artists/1
/artists/1/albums
/artists/1/albums/1
/artists/1/albums/1/songs
/artists/1/albums/1/songs/1
/artists/1/albums/1/songs/1/artists
/artists/1/albums/1/songs/1/artists/1
```

In an attempt to capture these URIs using Regexp, I whipped up the following ([live example](http://rubular.com/r/Aw8SNxzLOp)):

```
^\/(?<resource>(?:artists|albums|songs))(?:\/(?<id>\d+))?\/?$
```

When given a root-level resource such as the following, the regexp works as expects:

```
/artists
/songs/1
```

The first resulting matchdata has a resource of `artists` and an id of `nil` and the second has a resource of `songs` and an id of `1`.

But when given a URI that requests a resource's associations, such as `/albums/1/songs/1`, this regexp will fail because if doesn't account for recursion. So, I threw the whole thing in a non-capturing group with a 'one or more' (`+`) qualifier on it:

```
^(?:\/(?<resource>artists|albums|songs)(?:\/(?<identifier>\d+))?)+\/?$
```

This regexp now works on URIs such as `/albums/1/songs/2` but the resulting matchdata only contains the last resource (`songs`) and id (`2`).
I was expecting an Array containing two objects, one with a resource of `albums` and one with a resource of `songs`.

Is there a way properly use named captures within a capturing group that is using the 'one or more' qualifier?

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
"I know, I'll use regular expressions.". Now they have two problems.

Comment: *And some people, when confronted with regular expressions, think "I know, I'll use a catchy quote that I remember". Now they have added nothing to the discussion.* -- Tomalak

Comment: *At any rate, that's just my gut reaction to people misusing regexes.* --MДΓΓ БДLL.

Answer (score 0):

Most regex flavors do not work that way. Each capturing group will only contain the last substring it matched.
Unless you use .NET regex lib, which remembers every match of the capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

"Recursion" isn't really the right word for the problem you're having.  You're trying to iterate over multiple `/resource/id` pairs in your regex, then retrieve the individual captures afterward.  I suggest you use this regex instead:

```
\/(?<resource>artists|albums|songs)(?:\/(?<identifier>\d+))?
```

...and iterate over the `/resource/id` pairs in your code (e.g., with the `scan` method).

Comment: Problem with that is eg `/song/1foo/bar` will still match. So a pre-validation step is required, or using `\G` and making sure the match position is where you want it to be after all the matches.